# How can I implement Nearest Neighbor interpolation method in R?

Tags: r, voronoi

I have rainfall data that I want to interpolate using different interpolation methods. I have used `gstat` package to calculate IDW and Kriging methods.

But, I am wondering about any R package and related function that I can use to perform the nearest neighbor method in the R environment.

Can any one help please?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the data you used? Also an expected result would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Questions asking for package recommendations are regarded as opinion based and normally closed.  You can use google for such questions.  Also questions need to be focused and provide detailed reproducible input data and code attempt.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I should consider your suggestion. I am quite novice in this platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gstat package for this, just set nmin and nmax parameters to 1:

```
idw(formula = Var ~ 1, locations = spatdat, newdata = raster,
        nmax = 1, nmin = 1, force = T, debug.level = -1)
```